# Bootstrap working in local, but not on a server.

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just messing around with some web development stuff and with NFL season around the corner, I thought it would be good practice to make a Fantasy Football site. I am very early on, but I set up a navbar with bootstrap and it works fine when I run it locally, but when I try to run it on a Firebase server, it doesn't work at all. 
Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    <div class="container" name="navbar-container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fantasy Football</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="leagueList">My Leagues<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">League 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">League 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">League 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">My Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Game Day</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Waiver Wire</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try pulling the styles from the CDN using https as well.

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try https version of bootstrap.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css">
```

because Firebase uses HTTPS to serve content.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you